# Databricks SQL limiting results but need to fit critieria

Tags: python, sql, databricks

I have a regular audit where they require a random selection of files to audit.
However they need to see a number of specific conditions.
For example: If they need to see 6 files, 3 of them would need to be "R" from column B and 3 "TL" for column B. But it would also need to have 3 "Yes" from column C and 3 "No" from Column C.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | R | Yes |
| 2 | TL | No |
| 3 | R | Yes |
| 4 | TL | No |
| 5 | R | Yes |
| 6 | TL | No |
| 7 | R | Yes |
| 8 | TL | No |

This needs to be random so cant be a case of 3 equal "R" and "Yes" and 3 equal "R" and "No"

Comment: What is your question? Did you see [ask]? What code have you tried to solve this?